# how to preallocate a structure in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

I do have a simple question, but it doesn't go for me.
I want to preallocate a structure that contains many fields. I want to obtain it like this:
 structure S 1x30 and each of 30 fields should be a structure 1x50 (some of 50 entries integers, some cells with strings, some subarrays). Is this possible to preallocate it without giving the exact names for each of 50 fields?

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK struct fields must be named, however, those names don't need to be hard coded.

For example if I have a struct `foo` that has a field named `bar` I can access that field like so:

```
name = 'bar';
data = foo.(name);  % the same as data = getfield(data, name);
```

The `foo.(name)` notation indicates that one can make field names from variables (dynamic field names) for which the doc can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br1v5cc-1.html).
Additionally you can use this to create fields.

```
name = 'bar'
for i = 1:10
  nameI = [bar, num2str(i)] ;
  foo.( nameI) = []; % the same as foo = setfield(foo, nameI, []);
end
```

The struct `foo` now has 10 fields named `bar1`, `bar2`, ... `bar10`.

If you absolutely don't want names and simply want indicies then what you probably want is a cell array. Cell arrays are like regular matlab vectors except that they can contain anything.

```
c = {'1234', 1234, [1 2 3 4],  [1 2; 3 4], @disp, {1 ,2, 3}};
```

For example `c` is a cell array that contains a string, scalar, vector, matrix and then function handle, and another cell array.

You can access the contents of an individual cell using the curly braces `{}`.  So
`c{1}` would return `'1234'` whereas `c{2}` would return a number.

You could use either of these methods to pre-allocate a data structure that fits what you've described.

Comment: so this means I still have to enter something into each of my 50 fields, no convenient way of just entering the size of the structure or cell to be preallocated? that's a pity! :)

Comment: @beginh You can pre-allocate an array of structs.  For example `s = repmat(struct('bar', []), 50, 1);`

Comment: or maybe this way, what came to my mind: can I create a structure, that would be identical to the existing with all its fetures, number of cells etc, but just empty ? something like s = struct(obj) but empty inside..